# PHP Regex getting the last directory without file (or/and) parameters

Tags: php, regex, string, image, preg-match-all

Title is pretty much self explanatory but just to be more clear...

I want that all those 5 option :

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/?q=this/that/other
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/file.html
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/file.html?q=sometext
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/?q=sometext
```

will return:

```
http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/
```

So in other words...

Find the LAST ? (if exists) and THEN find the LAST `/` and ignore anything afterwards (no need to capture everything afterwards)

```
preg_match_all('/<a(.*?)href={HOW DO I SAY FIND THE **LAST ** /FROM THAT LINK, KEEP IT AND IGNORE EVERYTHING AFTERWARDS }>/s',$content,$images);
```

Comment: `preg_match_all('~.*/~', $str, $match);` https://regex101.com/r/zM3pD6/5

Comment: The regex solution fails if your URL is `http://example.com/?q=this/that/other`

Comment: @Andy Lester You are absolutely right ! And What is the solution for that ? Find the last ? if exists and THEN find the last /

Comment: The solution to that is to use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) first, and after that a simple `explode` on the path component …

Comment: @CBroe What you are saying that there is no solution via regex ?

Comment: I’m saying that this is _simpler_ …

Comment: The best tool for the job is usually one that's already been written. `parse_url` is a piece of code that is already written, tested and debugged, unlike whatever regex people come up with here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that :

```
$uri = "http://www.example.com/directory1/directory2/file.html";
$pos = strrpos($uri, "/");
$shortUri = substr(uri, 0, $pos);
```

Comment: As @Andy Lester said :: The regex solution fails if your URL is http://example.com/?q=this/that/other but it was my mistake I didn't mention that as an option and I know how to do clean it with foreach loop my question is how to do it on the fly via regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
preg_match_all('~[^\?]*/~', $str, $match);
```

to get everything without parts following `?`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is great but use the proper tool for the job:

```
$parts  = parse_url($url);
$result = $parts['scheme'].$parts['host'].$parts['path'];
```

You can use `dirname()` on the path if needed. Also notice there are other components that you may want such as port, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url)

which returns host, path and query separate.

```
// you can write something like
$url = parse_url($url);
$path = explode('/',$url['path']);
$lastDir = end($path);
```